# incrementing pointers in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=5,*b,*c;

    b=&a;
    c=b;

    *b++=*c++;

    printf(" %d %d %d\n",&a,b,c);
}
```

Here if adress of a is x, then value of b and c is both becoming x+4.  But shouldn't two ++ operator increase atleast one value by 8

Comment: No, `b` and `c` are independant.

Comment: Why do you think it would increase one by eight?

Comment: not a very good idea to print pointers like that.

Comment: After `int i=1; int j=i; i++, j++`, would you expect `i` and `j` to both hold `3`?

Comment: @user1495306, Pointers are better printed using `%p`, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5208673/89391

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is \*p++ different from \*p += 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221396/why-is-p-different-from-p-1) - it was quite easy for me to find that dupe... :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Don't confuse the value of a pointer with the value that it points *to*.

The expression `*b++` means: retrieve the value that b points *to*, and then increment the value of b.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%p` to format a pointer value, not `%d`.

All you are doing here is setting the value of `a` to itself via pointers.  Beware that both `b` and `c` may not be dereferenced after being incremented (because they point to a single value, not an array).

Note that if you want to increment the actual value, you must use parentheses:

```
(*b)++;
```

That will dereference `b` and increment the value.  If you do it without parentheses then it will increment the pointer and then dereference the original value.

Answer (score -1):

Please keep this in mind

*b++  this means that b is pointing to some integer and that integer value is being incrmented by  1 not by 2 as it might appear to you with two + signs.And if you want to print pointers, you should use %p format specifier for that rather than using int.

Comment: No, in `*b++`, `b` is incremented.