# structure array memory arrangement

Tags: c

```
struct abc filled[]={{"aa",10},{"bb",20}};    
   printf("[%u,%u]\n",filled,&filled);
   printf("[%u,%u]\n",filled[0],&filled[0]);

   printf("[%u,%u]\n",filled+1,&filled+1);
   printf("[%u,%u]\n",filled[1],&filled[1]);
```

how the filled array is arranged in memory? 
filled being the name of array returns the base address of the array...similarly &filled. but 
filled[0] gives some unknown value, may be the address and the googly part is &filled[0] which
gives the value 10. I am not able to get the logic. following is the output i am getting

```
[2293552,2293552]    
[4206592,10]    
[2293560,2293568]    
[4206595,20]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208641/difference-between-printing-a-memory-address-using-u-and-d-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
struct abc filled[]={{"aa",10},{"bb",20}};    
printf("[%u,%u]\n",filled,&filled);
printf("[%u,%u]\n",filled[0],&filled[0]);
```

Before we can discuss this any further, we need to have some idea of what "struct" looks like. You didn't provide a definition so I'm going to assume it is something like

```
struct abc {
    const char* str;
    int i;
};
```

So `filled` is an array of these objects:

```
filled[] = {
    struct abc { str = "aa", i = 10 },
    struct abc { str = "bb", i = 20 }
};
```

`filled[0]` refers to the first struct abc in the space.

```
{ str = "aa", i = 10 }
```

In memory, in a 32-bit build, these will be laid out, with [...] representing a byte:

```
[ptr][ptr][ptr][ptr][i][i][i][i]
```

On a 64-bit system, these will be laid out as

```
[ptr][ptr][ptr][ptr][ptr][ptr][ptr][ptr][i][i][i][i]
```

The exact order of the bytes that make up `str` and `i` will depend on the architecture.

Now, your code...

```
struct abc filled[]={{"aa",10},{"bb",20}};    
printf("[%u,%u]\n",filled,&filled);
printf("[%u,%u]\n",filled[0],&filled[0]);
```

printf has a limitation. The underlying function cannot actually see your arguments - it just gets data on a stack and it uses the print format *as a guide*.

Ultimately what's going horribly wrong is that you are passing a *struct* as a printf argument.

```
printf("[%u,%u]", filled[0], &filled[0]);
```

`filled[0]` resolves to a `struct abc`.

What's happening is that the program is putting the *value* of filled[0] onto the stack for printf to use. The first %u in the format mask consumes the `str` component and the second consumes the `i`.

If this is your complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct abc {
    const char* str;
    int i;
};

int main() {
    struct abc filled[] = { { "aa", 16 }, { "bb", 20 } };
    printf("filled = %p\n", filled);
    printf("&filled = %p\n", &filled);
    printf("filled[0] = %p\n", filled[0]);
    printf("&filled[0] = %p\n", &filled[0]);
    printf("filled[0].str = %p\n", filled[0].str);
    printf("filled[0].i = %d\n", filled[0].i);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
filled = 0xbfba5cb0
&filled = 0xbfba5cb0
filled[0] = 0x80485b0     <--+
&filled[0] = 0xbfba5cb0      | filled[0] actually printed the .str value
filled[0].str = 0x80485b0 <--+
filled[0].i = 16
```

What you are missing is the following compiler warning, because you're compiling with Visual Studio or without -Wall:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:12:5: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct abc’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("filled[0] = %p\n", filled[0]);
```

When you do

```
printf("[%u, %u]\n", filled[0], &filled[0]);
```

The program does the following:

```
push stack (const char*) "[%u, %u]\n"   // in 32-bit, 4-bytes of pointer.
push stack (struct abc) filled[0]       // pushes the entire of filled[0], str and i, 8 bytes.
push stack (struct abc*) &filled[0]     // pushes another 4 bytes.
```

And the resulting stack looks like this

[image]

printf never uses the value of "&filled[0]" because you didn't specify the right formats to read the data on the stack. If you instead used

```
printf("filled[0].str=%p, filled[0].i=%u, &filled[0]=%p\n", filled[0], &filled[0]);
```

then you would get more meaningful data, but this is a dangerous way to achieve the result because it makes a lot of assumptions about data layout and the stack.

Fundamentally, your problem is that you are doing this:

printf("%u", filled[0]);

where filled[0] is not a simple datatype.

Comment: thanks for the explaination...but that very well explains about the filled[0] value but what about &filled[0]...how &filled[0] gives 10.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar `filled[0]` is pushed completely onto the stack: first the pointer, then the int. The first `%u` takes the pointer - provided you are on a 32 bit system - the right way to print a pointer's value is with `%p` - and the 2nd `%u` takes the int. The `%filled[0]` is completely ignored.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar It's pushing `[ptr][ptr][ptr][ptr][i][i][i][i]` onto the stack. The first `%u` picks up the `ptr` part, the second `%u` picks up the `i` part, and nothing looks at '&filled[0]` because you only specified two format masks.

Comment: Try the following: `struct A { char a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h; }; struct A a = { 0xa, 0x10, 0x1a, 0x20, 0x3a, 0x40, 0x4a, 0x5a }; printf("%x %x\n", a);` ([live demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/k9fo3c)).

What happens is that "%x %x" expects 8 bytes of data. Instead, we're passing one argument that is 8 bytes of data big, and so it uses that.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar I've added some more details to the answer and included an image of what you're doing to the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Format specifier `%u` in `printf` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. You are supplying it with arguments of completely unrelated types: pointers and objects of struct type. Because of this your code exhibits *undefined behavior*. The code is broken and its output is completely meaningless. There's not much point in trying to analyze or explain it. (The explanation certainly exists, but it has nothing to do with the primary question.)

As for how arrays are arranged in memory... StackOverflow is choke-full of repetitive answers to this very question. Just do a search.

Comment: can u explain the behaviour why &filled[0] gives 10..?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar There is no explanation behind this. AndreyT already mentioned that **your code exhibits undefined behavior**.

Comment: Actually, there is a very simple explanation - he's passing a struct by value, the 10 is from his struct.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar: The "reason" for that is the complete misalignment of `printf` parameter stack area caused by the problems with the *previous* argument of `printf`. (If you attempt to print `&filled[0]` as *first* argument, the output will be different.) In other words, as I said before, your program prints fairly random garbage which cannot be explained in any way relevant to the main question.