# scanf %u negative number?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, unsigned, format-specifiers

I have tried `scanf("%u",&number)` and I have entered negative number the problem is when I `printf("%d",number)` I get the negative number. I thought this will prevent me from reading negative number.
Are `scanf("%d",&number)` and `scanf("%u",&number)` the same thing really ?
or is it only for readibility.

Am I doing something called undefined behavior so ?

EDIT:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string) I read this:

> %u : Scan for decimal unsigned int (Note that in the C99 standard the
> input value minus sign is optional, so if a minus sign is read, no
> errors will arise and the result will be the two's complement of a
> negative number, likely a very large value.

It is a little bit confusing reading SO answers and above. Can someone make it more clear ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208641/difference-between-printing-a-memory-address-using-u-and-d-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208641/difference-between-printing-a-memory-address-using-u-and-d-in-c Take a look at this link. It should answer your question.

Comment: @BlackBird Exact timing haha

Comment: none of these are proper, IMHO. to be exact, the problem is in signed and unsigned type.

Comment: @Module Yeah... haha

Comment: Please update your question to show us the declaration of `number`.

Comment: @rondino: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's undefined behavior, either way.

Considering variable `number` is of type `unsigned`, `%d` in `printf()` expects an argument of `signed` int type, passing an `unsigned` type is UB.

OTOH, if `number` is signed type, using `%u` for scanning is UB in first place.

As you might have expected

> *[...] prevent me from reading negative number*

format specifiers are **not** there to *prevent* improper input. If the format specifier does not match the supplied argument, it  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, annex J.2, scenarios invoking UB,

> The result of a conversion by one of the formatted input functions cannot be
>   represented in the corresponding object, or the receiving object does not have an
>   appropriate type

Comment: `printf("%u",-1)` is it also UB ?

Comment: @rondino technically, it is. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4664100/2173917)

Comment: @rondino: Yes, `printf("%u", -1)` has undefined behavior. `-1` is of type `int` and `%u` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. Corresponding signed and unsigned types can be interchangeable in some contexts, but *only* for values that are representable in both types.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in detail by Sourav Ghosh, using formats that are inconsistent with the actual types passed is a potential problem.  Yet for this particular case, on current PC architectures, this is not really a problem, as neither `int` nor `unsigned int` have trap representations.

You can scan a negative number with `scanf("%u", &number);`.  It will be negated in the destination type, namely `unsigned int`, with the same bitwise representation as the negative number in a signed `int`, for two's complement representation which is almost universal on current architectures.

> `scanf` converts `%u` by matching an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the value `10` for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer.
>
> The `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` functions convert the initial portion of the string pointed to by `nptr` to `long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long int`, and `unsigned long long int` representation, respectively. First, they decompose the input string into three parts: an initial, possibly empty, sequence of white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function), a subject sequence resembling an integer represented in some radix determined by the value of base, and a final string of one or more unrecognized characters, including the terminating null character of the input string. Then, they attempt to convert the subject sequence to an integer, and return the result.
>
> If the value of base is between 2 and 36 (inclusive), the expected form of the subject sequence is a sequence of letters and digits representing an integer with the radix specified by base, optionally preceded by a plus or minus sign, but not including an integer suffix.
>
> ... If the subject sequence has the expected form and the value of base is between 2 and 36, it is used as the base for conversion, ascribing to each letter its value as given above. If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type).

If the type of `number` is `unsigned int`, behavior is defined and the negative value is parsed and stored into `number` using the unsigned negation semantics.  Printing this value with `printf("%d", number);` is at best implementation defined, but again, on current PC architectures, will print the negative number that was originally parsed by `scanf("%u", &number);`

Conclusion: although it seems harmless, it is very sloppy to use `int` and `unsigned int` interchangeably and to use the wrong formats in `printf` and `scanf`.  As a matter of fact, mixing signed and unsigned types in expressions, esp. in comparisons is **very** error prone as the C semantics for such constructions are sometimes counter-intuitive.

Comment: "*It will be negated in the destination type, named `unsigned`, with the same bitwise representation as the negative number in a `signed int`.*" -- That's true only for 2's-complement representation (which is almost universal but not guaranteed).

Comment: @KeithThompson: correct.  I updated the answer. I cannot wait to see these obsolete possibilities to be removed from a future version of the C Standard.